# Python transliterator that holds the same rules as PHP one

Tags: python, php, internationalization, icu, transliteration

I need a transliterator for python that will be configured the same way as PHP one. My PHP based transliterator is configured with these rules:

```
$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(
    ':: NFD;'
    . ' :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove;'
    . ' :: NFC;'
    . ' :: [:Punctuation:] Remove;'
    . ' :: Lower();',
    Transliterator::FORWARD
);
```

At this moment I am using `slugify` library for python so that I can achieve a close enough result. This duality causes that cross-dependent (between php and python) transliterated texts must be done in PHP's site back-end by using an API endpoint that will return transliterated string.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Python has a built-in `str.translate()` method.

Comment: Mmmm it looks like the same, but how to configure it with php's like rules?

Comment: I'm not sure, since I'm not familiar with that PHP library.

Comment: If you want to convert a string to lowercase, just call `str.lower()`, you don't need to use a translation table. Just use the translation table for removing all the other character sets. The [`string`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-string-module) module has built-in strings that list various character classes.

Comment: Yeah but the most important part of the transliterator, which is normalizing to NFD and NFC standards is missing that way

Comment: I have no idea what those are.

Comment: PHP's intl is based on ICU, so if you find a Python implementation it should have equivalent functionality and runs on the same ruleset.

Comment: Mmmmmm PyICU looks promising

Answer (score 0):

Use `PyICU` a Python wrapper around icu4c.

Assuming you already have icu4c installed and accessible to Python, install PyICU:

```bash
pip install -U PyICU
```

Syntax is virtually identical between PyICU and PHP. The only real difference is that you need to add a label for the transliterator:

`icu.Transliterator.createFromRules(label, rules, direction)`

So:

```py
import icu
rules = (
    ':: NFD;'
    ' :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove;'
    ' :: NFC;'
    ' :: [:Punctuation:] Remove;'
    ' :: Lower();'
)
direction = icu.UTransDirection.FORWARD
transliterator = icu.Transliterator.createFromRules("customClean", rules, direction)
s = "Nāgārjuna!"
print(transliterator.transliterate(s))
# nagarjuna
```

Likewise PyICU will have equivalent functionality to PHP's intl.